# Add a button on the login form (D8)

Tags: hook, drupal-8

Is it possible to add a button on the basic login form?

```php
function alter_form_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id)
{
    if ($form_id == 'user_login_form') {
        ##ADD BUTTONS ???
        $form['#validate'] = ['test_validate'];
        $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'custom_submit_method';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a button in the `actions` wrapper using the following code

```
$form['actions']['custom_submit'] = [
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#name' => 'custom_submit',
  '#value' => t('My custom submit button'),
];
```

If you want to distinct both click, for example if you need to do something else when `custom_submit` is used, then you will need to access the `$form_state->getTriggeringElement();` in your `custom_submit_method` submission handler.

```
function custom_submit_method(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state){
    $trigger = $form_state->getTriggeringElement();
    if ($trigger['#name'] === 'custom_submit') {
      // ...
    }
}
```

You may find more documentation about

- Usage of `::getTriggeringElement`: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/223289/how-to-get-triggering-element
- Usage of custom submisson handler:
  https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/223342/add-a-custom-submission-handler-to-a-form

I hope my answer will help you.